# SQL via Batch - Not working well

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

I have written a batch script to get a particular value or update values from sql database. 
It works only for **some** times,listed below.

**case 1:**

- First time not works (not update) but returns - 1 rows affected
- Second time it works (update well in db) returns - 1 rows affected

**case 2:**

some times thrown an error (Sqlcmd: 'username=': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.)

Find my cmd error [here](http://oi67.tinypic.com/4rax4g.jpg).

Please find my script and sql code below.

**main.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

:: DB Properties
SET dbPath=XXXX 
SET dbUsername=YYYY
SET dbPassword=ZZZZ
SET dataBaseName=KKKK

:: SQL Properties
SET originId=50

ECHO DB NAME -  %dataBaseName%

ECHO Select an option
ECHO 1.Token
ECHO 2.Activate

SET /P option=Enter an option:

IF "%option%"=="1" ( SET /P inputUserName=Enter username: 
    sqlcmd -S %dbPath% -U %dbUsername% -P %dbPassword% -i token.sql -v dbName=%dataBaseName% username=%inputUserName% )

IF "%option%"=="2" ( SET /P inputUserName=Enter username: 
    sqlcmd -S %dbPath% -U %dbUsername% -P %dbPassword% -i update.sql -v dbName=%dataBaseName% username=%inputUserName% orgId=%originId% )

ECHO Executed Successfully ..!!

::PAUSE
```

**token.sql**

```
use $(dbName);

select VerificationCode from users where username = '$(username)'
```

**update.sql**

```
use $(dbName);

UPDATE users
SET passwordHash = (SELECT PasswordHash FROM users WHERE userid = $(orgId)),
    passwordsalt = (SELECT passwordsalt FROM users WHERE userid = $(orgId)),
    isActive = 1,
    emailConfirmed = 1
WHERE username = '$(username)'
```

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: "Does not work the first time, but does the second time" usually is a hint to a [delayed expansion problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) (there are two `if` blocks where this problem occures)

Comment: Thank you @Stephan. It works and got a nice explanation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

**1**. Enable the delayed expansion

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

**2**. Change the passed reference from  **%inputUserName%** to **!inputUserName!**

It works !!

Comment: Although this is the correct answer to your question, why don't you `set /p inputUserName=Enter username: ` once after `SET /P option=Enter an option:` and then just `if "%option%"=="1" sqlcmd ...` and  `if "%option%"=="2" sqlcmd ...` ?